# Are firewall logs filled with incoming SSDP requests typical for networks with a Windows 7 box?

Tags: firewall, logging, log-files, traffic, ssdp

While reviewing firewall logs that were sent to me from a Windows 7 box (the box is not a server) on a tiny network, I saw thousands of incoming SSDP UDP entries.  The SSDP entries were nearly constant, occurring every 3 seconds (approx 1200 log entries per hour).  The last time I was asked to review the logs for that network, I don't recall seeing such traffic.

The firewall log shows the SSDP traffic as incoming.  As expected, the protocol is UDP.  It is almost all coming from `::1` (loopback) over a single dynamic port (49152 - 65535) with a destination address of `ff02::c` (IPv6 link-local), port 1900.  The SSDPSRV service of Windows is the Windows service handling the requests.

Is this type of traffic normal for networks containing a Win7 box?

If not, what should be attempted to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this type of traffic normal for networks containing a Win7 box?

I'd expect to see it on any network that has Windows computers.

> What should be attempted to fix the issue?

Disable and stop the SSDP Discovery service on your Windows computers.

Comment: Thanks Joe. It seems like the SSDP service on the box is interrogating itself.  Am I misinterpreting the log, or is that basically what it is doing?  Is that normal?